# why doesnt it hide my div

Tags: jquery

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:15%;">
    <div id="out" align="center" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;width:300px;">
        <div id="out_text" align="center" style="margin-top:20;height:40px;width:200px;">
        Welcome
        </div>
        <form method="post"> 
            Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
            <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add User">
        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="in" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;width:300px;">
        <div id="in_text" align="center" style="margin-top:20;height:40px;width:200px;">
        "test"
        </div>
        <form>
            <input id="logout" type="submit" id="logout" value="Logout">    
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').show();
    $('#in').hide();
}); 

$('#login').click(function() {
    $('#out').hide();
    $('#in').show();
    $('#in_text').text("Success");
});

$('#logout').click(function() {
    $('#out').show();
    $('#in').hide();
    $('#out_text').text("Welcome");
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

so my question is why doesnt my $(document).ready hide the div with id="in" when the page finishes loading? i thought that was how it was done. am i missing something here? im looking through various tutorials and it see them do the same thing i am doing, but for some reason, my jquery is not working.

edit: ok so thanks to you guys, i was able to hide the other div. thank you. however, now i have a different problem. i am trying to make an onclick event handler that switches which div to display and change the text. i edited the code as following, can anyone here figure out why it doesnt work?

Comment: Are you checking errors and including jquery?

Comment: jQuery isn't built in to the browser.

Comment: OK now you have an unclosed `<script>` tag.

Comment: check my answer, you were missing TWO parens.  I think people were only noticing one or the other.

Comment: Please make sure you are showing the actual code you have trouble with before posting. It's *really* annoying when you keep editing out the mistakes people are pointing out. Take 2 minutes to review before you hit "post" instead of wasting the time of others.

Comment: i still answered your original problem, not really fair to be changing the question and the accepted answer after the fact.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for now.  Are you saying that new code isn't working?  did you check for errors?  Does it do anything?  Or just something different than you expected?

Comment: ok what is wrong with ppl on stackoverflow. yes i changed the question and excepted answer. when you answered it, it did solve an issue. but after a little while, another issue popped up that was related to this. so yes i kinda want to use this thread for problems related to that. do you guys want me to keep spamming forums with slightly altered versions of this code? and what do you mean not fair? when has helping someone out have something to do with fair?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `)` and more important you haven't included jQuery in your page.

```
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    ...
</head>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').show();
    $('#in').hide();
    $('#login').click(function() {
        $("p.hide-me-first").hide();
    }); // <---
}); // <---
```

Comment: I believe it is also prudent to note that [`.cssRule()` does not exist](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.cssRule).

Comment: right actually that login click function was a mistake i copied from somewhere. i fixed it now, and showed it above, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Daedalus it does, its a plugin.  http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerycssrule.  Also, he was missing two parens.

Comment: @thescientist That's a _plugin_, another `cssRule` method belongs to CSS Object Model.

Comment: @thescientist My point was that it wasn't included in the jQuery object.. whether its apart of a plugin or not is irrelevant, when they aren't even including such a plugin in their code.

Answer (score 2):

By checking your console you would see that you were missing two closing parens in your event handlers.  Also, it doens't look like you were including jquery.  Always check the console first when javascipt doesn't work.

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" style="margin-top:15%;">
    <div id="out" align="center" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;width:300px;">
        <div id="out_text" align="center" style="margin-top:20;height:40px;width:200px;">
        Welcome
        </div>
        <form method="post"> 
            Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input id="login" type="submit" value="Login">
            <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add User">
        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="in" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;width:300px;">
        <div id="in_text" align="center" style="margin-top:20;height:40px;width:200px;">
        "test"
        </div>
        <form>
            <input id="logout" type="submit" id="logout" value="Logout">    
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').show();
    $('#in').hide();
}); //missing paren here

$('#login').click(function() {
    jQuery.cssRule("p.hide-me-first", "display", "none");
});  //missing paren here
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/ihasev/2/edit

Also, make sure you are including the cssRule plugin

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$('#login').click(function() {
  jQuery.cssRule("p.hide-me-first", "display", "none");
};
```

That last line there should be:

```
});
```

When you have a syntax error in a script block, no code in that block will run.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `$(document).ready();` parenthesis, you should write this in your `<script>` tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#out').show();
    $('#in').hide();

    $('#login').click(function() {
        jQuery.cssRule("p.hide-me-first", "display", "none");
    });
});
```

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSsc4/) to show this solution.